# How to scale Images item GridView android?

Tags: android, android-layout

I have custom gridview with images, but I don't know how to scale items in the gridview when clicking on it. Could anyone help me?
I tried scale image in item gridview when i click on it.
This code in adapter .
But it dont't work !

```
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    final Animation animScale = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(mContext,
            R.anim.scale_anim);
    ObjMusicalType objMusical = mListMusical.get(position);
    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater inf = (LayoutInflater) mContext
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        convertView = inf.inflate(R.layout.item_grid_type, null);
        imgMenu = (ImageView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.img_type_musical);
    }

    imgMenu.setImageResource(objMusical.getImageMusical());
    imgMenu.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            try {
                Toast.makeText(mContext, "Click OK", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .show();
                imgMenu.startAnimation(animScale);
            } catch (Exception e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
    return convertView;

}
```

And this is file xml of item gridview

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <com.starsoft.musical.custom.SquareImageView
        android:id="@+id/img_type_musical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

File scale_anim.

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<scale
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="500"
    android:fromXScale="1"
    android:fromYScale="1"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:toXScale="1.5"
    android:toYScale="1.5" >
</scale>
```

Sorry ,but this is firt time I ask question in  stackover !
Thank for help

Comment: Can you explain more about what you are trying to do? Or give an example?

Comment: Thank you so much  ! David Wasser

Answer (score 0):

You should move convertView.findViewById to outside of if (convertView == null) block:

```
if (convertView == null) {
    LayoutInflater inf = (LayoutInflater) mContext
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    convertView = inf.inflate(R.layout.item_grid_type, null);
}
imgMenu = (ImageView) convertView
    .findViewById(R.id.img_type_musical);
```

but for better performance, you should use convertView.setTag like http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/listview.html

And also in OnClickListener, you need to change to something like:

```
imgMenu.setImageResource(objMusical.getImageMusical());
imgMenu.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    ImageView _imgMenu = imgMenu;
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        try {
            Toast.makeText(mContext, "Click OK", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show();
            _imgMenu.startAnimation(animScale);
        } catch (Exception e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
});
```

to avoid all your OnClickListener call startAnimation on same ImageView.

Comment: Thank for your answer xtr .But if I try startAnimation in adapter it doesn't work.